# AWS ECS/FARGATE - Service task running but no container instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm trying to deploy a docker container image with an API to AWS using ECS/FARGATE and while the service task **appears** to be running, it **doesn't have a container instance associated** with it and so I cannot communicate with my API. I'm not very experienced in AWS in general, so I apologise in advance if I'm making a rookie mistake.

#### What I tried

1. Created the ECR, pushed my docker image
2. Created the cluster
3. Created the task definition:

```
{
  "ipcMode": null,
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:...:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "environmentFiles": null,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "secretOptions": null,
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/my-task-definition",
          "awslogs-region": "eu-central-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      },
      "entryPoint": null,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 5001,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 5001
        }
      ],
      "command": null,
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 0,
      "environment": [ //environmnet variables  ],
      "resourceRequirements": null,
      "ulimits": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "secrets": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": null,
      "memoryReservation": null,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "stopTimeout": null,
      "image": "<<ECR_ID>>.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/<<CONTAINER_NAME>>:<<TAG_ID>>",
      "startTimeout": null,
      "firelensConfiguration": null,
      "dependsOn": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": {
        "retries": 3,
        "command": [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -f localhost:5001/status"
        ],
        "timeout": 5,
        "interval": 30,
        "startPeriod": null
      },
      "essential": true,
      "links": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "<<CONTAINER_ID>>"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": "2048",
  "taskRoleArn": "arn:...:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "compatibilities": [
    "EC2",
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:893482549503:task-definition/my-task-definition:12",
  "family": "my-task-definition",
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.24"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.container-health-check"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
    }
  ],
  "pidMode": null,
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "cpu": "256",
  "revision": 12,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "inferenceAccelerators": null,
  "proxyConfiguration": null,
  "volumes": []
}
```

4. Created the service, using the task definition. Also connected it to my application load balancer.
5. In EC2 I added a new `ecs-optimized` instance and connected it to the cluster by doing:
   `ECS_CLUSTER=my-cluster >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config` from inside the instance.
6. I run the task from the service.

#### Result

- I see the application running from the task logs:
  [image: Tasks logs]

But I cannot get any response from `curl` from my computer. I am trying to send the requests to my **load balancer** and even the **Public IP** address provided by the task:
[image: Task information]

- From the cluster view, I see the running task with **no container instance**:

[image: Running task with no container instance]

- In the ECS Instances task, I see the EC2 assigned with **no running tasks**:
  [image: cluster view - ECS instances task]
- Also the **health check appears to be failing**, as the task **stops and restarts** every few minutes.

I have followed several tutorials on the matter and none seem to solve the problem. Any tips are welcomed and if some information is missing I'll be happy to add it.

Comment: Have you checked the security group attached to your service? You're trying to access public IP but is the instance in a public subnet (a subnet with a internet gateway that is routeable). What should the infrastructure look like?

Comment: Is the right port exposed in your Docker container?

Comment: Hey @chris, the security group is the one that was created by default when creating the service. I understand that I calling the public ip directly is not the way to go, that's why I'm trying to call the Application load balancer DNS.

Comment: @Paolo, the Dockerfile has `EXPOSE 5001`

Comment: What instance do you use. Is it large enough to support 2048 MB task?

Comment: Hey @Marcin! I have attached a t2.micro instance, which I know is small, but the thing is that I don't see any Container Instance associated to the running task.

Comment: @BrunoFischetti you're runnin gon Fargate the container so it would not be using your EC2 cluster, instead it would launch the serverless container on infrastructure in AWS account

Comment: The launch type for the service is Fargate, so it is not scheduling the Tasks on your EC2 instance but in an AWS managed environment. To make your web-page accessible from the internet, you need to open the correct Ports at the Load Balancers Security Group to the CIDR 0.0.0.0/0 and allow the Security Group of the Load Balancer to have access on the right port at the Security Group of the Task.